# Do weapons' damage types (P/S/B) have any effect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, damage-types

Does the type of weapon used (piercing, slashing, bludgeoning) have any effect in Pathfinder RPG? For example, in AD&D 2e, the type of weapon modifies attack rolls according to the defender's armor type. (E.g., piercing weapons have an attack bonus on chain mail and so on…) Does something like this exist in Pathfinder too?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. There are consequences for the weapon type used, but modifiers against armour types have been discarded.

**DR:** Some monsters are resistant to certain types of damage. This can be seen in DR for  [skeletons](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/skeleton.html) where their DR is 5/Bludgeoning.

**Feats:** Some feats also require certain weapon types to be effective, for example [Bleeding Critical](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/feats.html#_bleeding-critical) requires a slashing or piercing weapon to be used.

**Smashing:** [Smashing objects](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/additionalRules.html#smashing-an-object) requires a blungeoning or slashing weapon.

**Magic weapons:** Certain [magical weapon](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/weapons.html) effects can only be applied to certain weapons. For example [keen](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/weapons.html#weapons-keen) can only be applied to piercing or slashing melee weapons.

Comment: You might want to leave accepting an answer a little longer in case I've missed anything, or indeed someone finds a case where I'm wrong :)

Comment: Also, some enchantments can only be placed on certain types of weapons.

Comment: Cheers, will add that

Comment: Ok, but i think it's answered already, thank you. :)

Comment: May as well add as much info as possible, for the next person who comes looking for the same thing.

Comment: it's definitely an edge case, but being swallowed whole requires you to use piercing or slashing to escape, if memory serves.  Also, some oozes only split with certain damage types (typically either slashing or both piercing and slashing, which is the balancing-case for swallow whole monsters...  and what if an ooze has swallow whole?!).